# Linphone android Incoming Early Media example

Tags: android, sip, linphone, linphone-sdk

I am working on the Linphone Android source code and I am trying to use the *callState* **CallIncomingEarlyMedia** to show video in the CallIncomingActivity. Does anyone got any example how to do this?

I have tried to use *acceptEarlyMediaWithParams()* instead of *acceptCallWithParams()* in the LinphoneManager.java but it doesn't show the video.

any ideas?